# Variable in struct receives error undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c

This is a small snippet of my code that seems to be part of the problem.

```
struct File {
    int *childrenDir[10];
    int childDirIndex;
};

struct File *File_create() {
    struct File *file = malloc(sizeof(struct File));
    assert(file != NULL);

    file->childDirIndex = 0;

    return file;
}

struct File currentDir[20];
int curDirIndex = 0;

root = *File_create();
currentDir[curDirIndex] = root;

void overhead() {
    currentDir[curDirIndex].childrenDir[childDirIndex] = 0;
    currentDir[curDirIndex].childDirIndex++;
    fileID++;
}
```

When I would call overhead() from other functions, the compiler would throw an error back at me.

```
‘childDirIndex’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I'm not exactly sure why it'd give me this error when I thought I declared childDirIndex whenever I call File_create().

Comment: `childDirIndex` is member of `struct File`. You need an instance of `File` in order to access that `File`'s `childDirIndex` member. You can't access `childDirIndex` without an instance of a `File`. Perhaps you meant `currentDir[curDirIndex].childDirIndex`?

Comment: The first line of `overhead` is wrong as @Cornstalks said. Also, you can't initialize a global with a function call. So `root = *File_create();` is wrong, too. Recommend you read more about C syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void overhead() {
    currentDir[curDirIndex].childrenDir[childDirIndex] = 0;
//                                      ^ This is the trouble!
    currentDir[curDirIndex].childDirIndex++;
    fileID++;
}
```

Maybe you mean:

```
void overhead() {
    currentDir[curDirIndex].childrenDir[currentDir[curDirIndex].childDirIndex++] = 0;
    fileID++;
}
```

Or, more sanely and readably:

```
void overhead() {
    struct File *fp = &currentDir[curDirIndex];
    fp->childrenDir[fp->childDirIndex++] = 0;
    fileID++;
}
```